# Creating a menu while categorizing my products

Tags: routes, commerce

Hello I am developing an e-commerce website with drupal commerce(commerce kickstart) everything seems great.I have imported my products and I have tested it and I made my catalog like the video on vimeo that it is posted http://vimeo.com/22748684.

But I would like to make this catalog as a drop down menu.I mean I want to a menu with jquery  that it will replace this catalog and the user for example can see a subcategory cars and can choose Toyota, BMW, some other with tyres like my products on the catalog.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish) to replace the default main menu that comes with commerce kickstart, however you use it at a cost since this jquery drop down menus are usually not optimized for mobile, although superfish provides some optimizations (most in a beta state right now).

Anyway if you need a *big* dropdown menu your alternatives are short, and Superfish provides minimal mobile browser support if used with a responsive theme (auto-resize and support for touch devices).

Comment: Yes it does. please check http://dcj.joshics.in on your mobile device!