# How to use superfish on commerce kickstart

Tags: commerce, navigation

Anyone can tell me the steps needed to implement superfish on commerce kickstart 2.32 ?

I have read this ([Creating a menu while categorizing my products](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38509/creating-a-menu-while-categorizing-my-products/64320#64320)) but I failed.

Comment: Do you want superfish for the main site menu or some other menu? What have you tried in terms of installing the superfish module as per the instructions on its project page and adding a superfish menu? What does "i failed" mean? do you get errors, does something look or act broken, etc?

Comment: @rooby, I have managed to install superfish (module and libraries). And it shows the parent-child menu structure too. Now, superfish put the menu on the right side (on the header). I want it to put the menu on the left side. How to do that?

Comment: Usually blocks will arrange in a region from left to right so you would just have to make sure the superfish block is first in the region you are putting it in. It depends on what theme you use and your block configuration though so there is no one correct answer that we could give here. There is also the possibility that the theme you use doesn't support superfish menus out of the box and needs additional CSS changes.